# Intersection of radical primal ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ a noetherian ring, $a_{1},...,a_{n}$ primary ideals, with $rad(a_{i})=m_{i} $ maximal ideal and $m_{i}\neq m_{j}$ si $i\neq j$. How can I prove that $a_{1}\cap a_{2}\cap \ldots\cap a_{n}=a_{1}\ldots a_{n}$?

Comment: What do you want to prove?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot complete it.

Comment: No, in this exercise it is a maximal ideal

Answer (score 1):

This should remind you of part of the statement of the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings). Recalling the condition there, it would be nice to prove that $\mathfrak{a}_i + \mathfrak{a}_j = A$ for $i \neq j$. Here's a silly observation that helps: in general $1 \in \mathfrak{b}$ if and only if $1 \in \operatorname{rad}(\mathfrak{b})$.

Just a remark: we don't need the concept of a primary ideal for the above, but it's a good exercise to show that if $\operatorname{rad}(\mathfrak{b})$ is maximal then $\mathfrak{b}$ is primary.